# how to get session values to textbox when checkbox is clicked in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm having two pages with similar textboxes when user inserts data into first page and goes to next page, if he need to give same data am adding a checkbox, when user clicks it same data which is in session from before page has to be get into the second page variables through ajax. can someone help me please. thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far - so developers here can help you easily.

Comment: well send ajax request to php and get the session value when checked the checkbox.

Comment: hi dipesh can you please send some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Response for the Comment**

I made sample code which will give you idea about how to can do this.

**jQuery Code for checkbox change event**

```
$(function(){

    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'script.php',
                success : function(session)
                {
                    $('input:text').val(session);
                }
            });
        }

    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['name_of_the_session_variable'];
exit;
?>
```

**EDIT**

```
$("#checked").click(function()
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {   
        $('#provisional_total_public_funding').val(<?php echo empty($this->session->store['actual_info']['actual_total_public_funding']) ? '' : $this->session->store['actual_info']['actual_total_public_funding']; ?>);
    }
});
```

**Ajax Request Response**

```
<select name="fin_year" id="fin_year">
    <option value="" >Please select an year</option>
    <option value="<?= $actFinYr; ?>"><?= $actFinYr; ?></option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $('#fin_year').change(function()
        {
            var options = $(this);
            if(options.val() != '')
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url     : 'CODEIGNITER_HTTP_URL/'+options.val(),
                    beforeSend : function()
                    {
                        //show loading
                    },
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        //play with the response from server.
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: $("#checked").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
  document.getElementById("provisional_total_public_funding").value = "<?php echo empty($this->session->store['actual_info']['actual_total_public_funding']) ? '' : $this->session->store['actual_info']['actual_total_public_funding']; ?>";
            alert("Checked!");
        }
   
}); i gave as above

Comment: Yes that is correct too...but there is modification needed...use jQuery selector,  see my updated answer,

Comment: can we give value of session directly in jquery instead of session

Comment: well for that you need to store some hidden fields and set posted data into that hidden fields.

Comment: hi dipesh i have one more doubt. am having a drop down box after selecting am calling a function in that how i have to use ajax call to post that value to controller in codeigniter. can you help me please

Comment: well i do not codeigniter much but if you are using jquery then i can help you in posting that value to specific action...you need to use `.change` event handler in jquery and when drop down change send `$.ajax` request.

Comment: <select name="fin_year" id="fin_year" onChange="get_actual_details();">
    <option value="" >Please select an year</option>
    <option value="<?= $actFinYr; ?>"><?= $actFinYr; ?></option>
    
</select> and script is <script>
function get_actual_details(){
alert("hi");
}

</script> in this how i have to give

Comment: hi dipesh,i gave as follows function get_actual_details(){
alert("hi");

var form_data = {
    fin_year: $('#fin_year').val(),
    
    is_ajax: 1
    
   };
   $.ajax({
    cache : false,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'get_actual_details',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response)
    {
     if (response != 'failed') {
     
     }
    }
   });
} and in controller as function get_actual_details(){
 if(isset($_POST['is_ajax']) && $_POST['is_ajax']) {
        $fin_year = empty($_POST['fin_year']) ? '' : $_POST['fin_year'];
     }
     
 } how to know whether data is getting or not

Comment: yeah the value is getting posted  how to print that value from controller

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery like this:

**HTML 1st page:**

```
input1 <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"/>
input2 <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2"/>
```

**jQuery 1st page:**

```
$input1 = $("#input1");
$input2 = $("#input2");
$input1.keydown(function(){
    $.post("yourPHP.php", {input1: $input1.val()});
});
$input2.keydown(function(){
    $.post("yourPHP.php", {input1: $input1.val()});
});
```

**PHP 1st page:**

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();    
}
if(isset($_POST['input1'])){
    $_SESSION['input1'] = $_POST['input1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['input2'])){
    $_SESSION['input2'] = $_POST['input2'];
}
```

**HTML 2nd page:**

```
input1 <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"/>
input2 <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2"/>
<br/>
radio1 <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"/>
radio2 <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"/>
```

**jQuery second page:**

```
$input1 = $("#input1");
$input2 = $("#input2");
$radio1 = $("#radio1");
$radio2 = $("#radio2");
$radio.click(function(){
    $.post("yourPHP.php", {request: "input1"}, function(data){
        $input1.val(data);
    });
});
$input2.keydown(function(){
    $.post("yourPHP.php", {request: "input2"}, function(data){
        $input2.val(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP 2nd page:**

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();    
}
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
    switch($POST['request']){
        case 'input1':
            echo $_SESSION['input1'];
            break;  
        case 'input2':
            echo $_SESSION['input2'];
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope it works.